# Save each partition of dataframe into seperate single file in HDFS/S3

Tags: apache-spark

I have a requirement to save each partition of a spark data frame into separate single dynamic name file in HDFS, Any ideas how to implement using spark parallelization methods

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using `DataFrame.repartition()` method. The problem with using `coalesce(1)` is that your parallelism drops to 1, and it can be slow at best and error out at worst. Increasing that number doesn't help either -- if you do `coalesce(10)` you get more parallelism, but end up with 10 files per partition.

To get one file per partition without using `coalesce()`, use `repartition()` with the same columns you want the output to be partitioned by.

```
import spark.implicits._
df.repartition($"col1", $"col2", $"col3", $"col4", $"col5").write.partitionBy("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5").mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet("$location")
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any option to save the file based on partition column  dynamically